# Cake php 3.4.6 data pull giving wrong value and returning object

Tags: php, cakephp

I have been trying to pull data from cake. But I keep on getting the object data when I view via print_r

```
$userDetails =  $this->UserDetails->find()->where(['UserDetails.user_id' => $id])->all();
print_r($userDetails);
```

Result

`Cake\ORM\ResultSet Object ( [items] => Array ( [0] => App\Model\Entity\UserDetail Object ( [id] => 6 [user_id] => 10 [firstName] => Rey Norbert [lastName] => Besmonte [address] => [contact] => [age] => [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2017-05-24T03:10:55+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => ) [modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2017-05-24T03:10:55+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => ) [[new]] => [[accessible]] => Array ( [*] => 1 [id] => ) [[dirty]] => Array ( ) [[original]] => Array ( ) [[virtual]] => Array ( ) [[errors]] => Array ( ) [[invalid]] => Array ( ) [[repository]] => UserDetails ) ) )`

I am not sure why `ake\ORM\ResultSet Object ( [items] => Array ( [0] => App\Model\Entity\UserDetail Object` is showing.

In php cake 2.x I have no problem with this.

Comment: you want array instead of object ?

Comment: yup that is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cakephp 3.x outputs object instead of array().
If you want array you can us**e toArray()**;

**Example:-**

```
$userDetails =  $this->UserDetails->find('all')->where(['UserDetails.user_id' => $id])->toArray();
print_r($userDetails);
```

And if you want to return only single row then you can use **first()**

**Example:-**

```
$userDetails =  $this->UserDetails->find('all')->where(['UserDetails.user_id' => $id])->first();
print_r($userDetails);
```

Comment: it just turn the object to array, i would like for it to be return as
------------------>           
([id] => 6 [user_id] => 10 [firstName] => Rey Norbert [lastName] => Besmonte [address] => [contact] => [age] => [created] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2017-05-24T03:10:55+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => ) [modified] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object ( [time] => 2017-05-24T03:10:55+00:00 [timezone] => UTC [fixedNowTime] => )

Comment: thanks its working now.. still getting a hang of red velvet. so much different from 2.x cake.

Answer (score 0):

- The query’s execute() method is called. This will return the
  underlying statement object, and is to be used with
  insert/update/delete queries.
- The query’s first() method is called. This will return the first
  result in the set built by SELECT (it adds LIMIT 1 to the query).
- The query’s all() method is called. This will return the result set
  and can only be used with SELECT statements.
- The query’s toArray() method is called.

Use any of this according to your requirment :

```
$userDetails =  $this->UserDetails->find()->where(['UserDetails.user_id' => $id])->all();
```